# I was once a fan of..? or I was a fan of...?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I would like to know if it would be okay to use

> ”I was once a fan”

or

> “I was a fan”

.

Comment: Both sentences are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences could have slightly different meanings.

If you were a fan of Big McBig but you went off him, you could say

> I was once a fan of Big McBig.

If you were a fan until the day he retired, you could say

> I was a fan of Big McBig.

Answer (score 0):

**"Was once a fan" implies that the person is no longer a fan** (there is, however, an idiomatic expression *"Once a ____, always a ____"*). "Was a fan" does not allude to the current state of the person described. The second sentence is always correct, the first is only correct when the person is no longer a fan.